# Ethers.js and Ethereum Sending Transaction

Tags: ethereum, blockchain

I have set up all the crypto wallet app and I'm struggling on this part to send the transfer. After submitting and getting all needed details it refuses to be sent. The problems seems to start on transactionHash line.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

import { contractABI, contractAddress } from "../utils/constants";

export const TransactionContext = createContext();

const { ethereum } = window;

console.log(ethers);

const createEthereumContract = () => {
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

  return transactionContract;
}

export const TransactionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState("");
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [transactionCount, setTransactionCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("transactionCount") || 0);

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      ...value
    }));
  }

  const checkWalletIsConnected = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Make sure you have metamask!");

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });

      accounts.length !== 0 ? setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]) : console.log("No authorized account found");

      console.log(accounts);
    } catch (error) {

      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("Error checking wallet connection");
    }
  }

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Make sure you have metamask!");

      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      throw new Error("Error connecting wallet");

    }
  }

  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (ethereum) {
      const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
      const transactionContract = createEthereumContract();
      const parsedAmount = ethers.parseEther(amount);

      await ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        params: [{
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: ethers.toBeHex(parsedAmount)
          }],
      });

      console.log(transactionContract);
      const transactionHash = await transactionContract.addToBlockchain(addressTo, parsedAmount, message, keyword);
      console.log("Transaction hashing");

      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log(`Loading...${transactionHash}`);
      await transactionHash.wait();
      console.log("Transaction mined");
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(`Success! ${transactionHash}`);
 
      const transactionCount = await transactionContract.getTransactionCount();
  
      setTransactionCount(transactionCount.toNumber());
    }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new Error("Error sending transaction");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWalletIsConnected();
  }, []);

  return (
    <TransactionContext.Provider value={{ connectWallet, currentAccount, handleChange, formData, sendTransaction }}>
      {children}
      </TransactionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I'm getting every time I want to do the transfer. I have checked everything and all the part seem to work normally.

```
Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.2)
    at makeError (errors.ts:677:21)
    at assert (errors.ts:694:25)
    at send (contract.ts:288:9)
    at Proxy.addToBlockchain (contract.ts:330:22)
    at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.jsx:84:57)
```